# formatting the date with future dates

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem formatting my date in javascript and adding an additional date in advance.

The code functions well but in ugly format, can you check on my code and tell me where should I put on the additional days in the code.

```
<p id="advancedate"></p>
<script>

function addWorkDays(startDate, days) {
    if(isNaN(days)) {
        return
    }
    if(!(startDate instanceof Date)) {  
        return
    }


    var dow = startDate.getDay();
    var daysToAdd = parseInt(days);


    if (dow == 0)
        daysToAdd++;

    if (dow + daysToAdd >= 6) {

        var remainingWorkDays = daysToAdd - (5 - dow);

        daysToAdd += 2;
        if (remainingWorkDays > 5) {

            daysToAdd += 2 * Math.floor(remainingWorkDays / 5);

            if (remainingWorkDays % 5 == 0)
                daysToAdd -= 4;
        }
    }
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);
    return startDate;
}



var today = new Date(),
    month = today.getMonth(),
    date = today.getDate(),
    day = today.getDay();
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]; 
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

document.getElementById("advancedate").innerHTML = addWorkDays = (weeks[day] + "," + months[month] + " " + date ); //Saturday,May 11
//document.getElementById("advancedate").innerHTML = addWorkDays(today, 14); //Wed May 15 2019 09:51:41 GMT+0800
  </script>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML = addWorkDays =` ... addWorkDays is a **function**, you need to call it - like you do in the commented code below that, but then you need to getMonth, getDate etc on the returned value

Comment: if make like this document.getElementById("advancedate").innerHTML = addWorkDays(weeks[day] + "," + months[month] + " " + date, 14); i get undefined

Comment: no, because your function expects a D, and returns a Date - so, the innerHTML would be set to `undefined`, since it would *fail* at `if(!(startDate instanceof Date))`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't want `addWorkDays` to *mutate* the incoming date, I would suggest the following addition

```
function addWorkDays(startDate, days) {
    if(isNaN(days)) {
        return
    }
    if(!(startDate instanceof Date)) {  
        return
    }
    // avoid changing the passed in Date object
    startDate = new Date(startDate);

    var dow = startDate.getDay();
    var daysToAdd = parseInt(days);
    /// ... rest of your code
}
```

Though, that's not necessary, depends on usage

Now to use it correctly (regardless of change above)

```
var today = new Date();
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]; 
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var future = addWorkDays(today, 14),
    month = today.getMonth(),
    date = today.getDate(),
    day = today.getDay();
document.getElementById("advancedate").innerHTML = (weeks[day] + "," + months[month] + " " + date ); //Saturday,May 11
```

Answer (score -1):

Use momentjs and you can do it with just a single line.

https://momentjs.com/

for example, you can add days just like

```
moment().add(7, 'days').format('LLL')
```